# Magento 2 - Cant use product factory in plugin

Tags: magento2, product, plugin

I try to add a new product in a **afterSave** plugin for **Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface**, but I get:

> Type Error occurred when creating object:
> Company\Quote\Plugin\RalSpecialColorPriceSurcharge, Argument 3 passed
> to Company\Quote\Plugin\RalSpecialColorPriceSurcharge::__construct()
> must be an instance of Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory, instance
> of Magento\Framework\App\Config given, called

**app\code\Company\Quote\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="company_quote_ral_specialcolor_price_surcharge" 
                type="Company\Quote\Plugin\RalSpecialColorPriceSurcharge"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Company\Quote\Plugin\RalSpecialColorPriceSurcharge.php**

```
<?php

namespace Company\Quote\Plugin;

use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory;

class RalSpecialColorPriceSurcharge
{
    /**
     * @var Company\Quote\Model\Config\Settings
     */
    private $settings;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

   ...
```

Comment: What is your plugin method, show that?

Comment: It is not relevant, it breaks in the constructor already, I am not even using the productFactory in the plugin method yet. If I remove it from the constructor then the code works again.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The problem was, that I executed `bin/magento setup:di:compile` earlier, which means that the code is getting compiled into the static files and loaded from there.

So if you call it once, then you always have to call it again after making changes to the constructor.